# Add limit bar on my progress circle with progressbar.js

Tags: javascript, progress-bar, jquery-ui-progressbar

I got a circle bar like this example : [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kimmobrunfeldt/72tkyn40/) and I would like to add a limit bar like this : [Circle Bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kxuJo.png)

But I want a limit bar alterable with a value like with : `"bar.animate(value);"` for the blue bar.

How can I proceed to make this ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Check `animate()` function. The docs don't specify this, so i think this answer could be usefull.

At the bottom:

```
bar.animate(1.0);  // Number from 0.0 to 1.0 or (88/100 => 0.88) for 88 %)
```